# Delphi, Firedac TFDTable.CreateTable doesn't exist

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe6, firedac

I have DELPHI-XE6 and tried to use FireDacs TFDTable.CreateTable to create a db-table but it say's "TFDTable does not contain a member with name CreateTable".

Is that so that XE6 is to old or what?
The code looks like:

```
function TDataModule1.crtTable(const aTblName: string;
  const aFlds: TStringList): boolean;
var
  Table: TFDTable;
begin
  Table := TFDTable.Create(nil);
  try
    Table.Connection := FDConnection1;
    { specify table name }
    Table.TableName := aTblName;
    { add some fields }
    Table.FieldDefs.Add('ID', ftInteger, 0, False);
    Table.FieldDefs.Add('Name', ftString, 50, False);
    { define primary key index }
    Table.AddIndex('pkMyTableID', 'ID', '', [soPrimary]);
    { and create it; when the first parameter is True, an existing one is dropped }
    Table.CreateTable(False);
  finally
    Table.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: I cannot say in which version it was introduced, but it was definitely one of the later ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might not be the most accurate method, but based on the Embarcadero documentation, I would say it has been introduced with **XE7**. It seems 
`TFDTable` wasn't moved and is in the same namespace - `FireDAC.Comp.Client` - in both versions, so the links depending on version should be:

[XE7 documentation of FireDAC.Comp.Client.TFDTable.CreateTable](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE7/en/FireDAC.Comp.Client.TFDTable.CreateTable) - Page exists with basic info

[XE6 documentation of FireDAC.Comp.Client.TFDTable.CreateTable](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE6/en/FireDAC.Comp.Client.TFDTable.CreateTable) - nothing

To verify I looked at the [method list for TFDTable](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE6/en/FireDAC.Comp.Client.TFDTable_Methods) in XE6, with no match found.

Comment: Ok, that's it. So I have to give up this thing. I'll think I can manage without it. But thank's anyway.